# How to handle large option sets in Android?

Tags: android, numberpicker, android-number-picker

I am building an app that needs an input controller that helps users select from a range of possible values, usually numbering between 100 and 150. At the same time the user should be able to freely modify the final value if the available options do not suit their needs. In our iOS version we do this using a simple Picker which updates a UITextField, shown below:

[image]

The user can scroll to a preferred value in the Picker and then modify their input through the the UITextField. This works well in iOS because the Picker can be scrolled very quickly. Also, when keyboard, Picker and UITextField are showing, neither gets in the way of the other.

I've now been trying for a couple of days do do something similar in Android but haven't had any luck. To begin with, the standard NumberPicker is very slow and does not handle scrolling through the set of values too well. Also, when selecting the EditText there doesn't seem to be a way to reliably ensure that all tree key elements remain visible on screen.

This is probably somewhat of an open ended question, but I'm really just looking for ideas on how this problem could be solved in Android without negatively affecting the app's usability.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at AutoCompleteTextView ? The user starts filling in first characters and a dropdown displays matching elements. I am using it for 36k entries and it works fine for decent phones.

Else, there must be custom made components here and there that could be your building base to deliver the expected user experience.

Any properly set up listview of edittexts should scroll fast enough.

Did you look at other Android application facing the same user experience challenge to study existing solutions ?

Comment: Yes, that's how its currently implemented. The problem however is that we want to present the user with all the available options. So I modified the AutoCompleteTextView to resent all options as soon as it's selected and the results are not pretty. For once it's impossible to scroll to the current selection, also it tends to hide the EditText when both the keyboard and dropdown are showing.

Comment: yes, I see what you mean, AutocompleteTextView can be messy. You have ways to control the dropdown windows more precisely but it might not be good enough. and what about the listview implementation : few rows displayed, freedom in design...